# Google Calendar API eventResponse.getHtmlLink() - how to get event url allowing "add video call"

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

After calling [events:insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) API, we obtain event url using `response.getHtmlLink()`.

The url looks like this: https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=`<event_id>`.

Opening in browser, it shows a view of the event, where "add video call" link is not present:

[image]

However, if I navigate to this inserted event from Google calendar UI, the url is like this: https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?pli=1#eventpage_6%7Ceid-`<event_id>`-1-0-.

It shows a view of the event, with the "add video call" link present:

[image]

How do I get the editable view (2nd case) url to an event, via the API?

Comment: When creating the event, I set the creator. However, in latest API example, creator doesn't exist anymore. Could that be an issue? https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

Answer (score 0):

Use [Events: get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get#try-it)

[image]

I get a `htmlLink` response:

```
{
"htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=..."
}
```

Clicking the link led me to this page:

[image]

If you need the `hangoutLink`, then include it in the 'fields' as well.
[image]

Comment: I do use .htmlLink to get the event link. However, I still don't see the video link. I suspect if it has anything to do with how the event is created.

Comment: There's no file resource called 'videoLink'. Have you tried the hangoutLink?

Comment: to clarify, I'm calling .htmlLink from the Event.create response, which is the created event. By "no video link", I meant in the webpage UI of htmlLink, I don't see a UI section for "video link".

Comment: I also tried Event.get on an event on my calendar, and in the htmlLink web UI, I still don't see the "Video call" section.